# I'm not getting the commas in the Bibliography!

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, jabref

I'm managing my references with JabRef.

These are the references I'm referring to:

```
@ARTICLE{Deryugina1998,
  author = {Deryugina E. I., Bourdon M. A., Reisfeld R. A. \&Strongin A.},
  title = {Remodeling of collagen matrix by human tumor cells requires activation
    and cell surface association of matrix metalloproteinase-2.},
  journal = {Cancer Res.},
  year = {1998},
  volume = {58},
  pages = {3743–3750},
  owner = {Giovanni},
  timestamp = {2013.06.21}
}

@ARTICLE{Fey2002,
  author = {Fey P., Stephens S., Titus M. A. \& Chisholm R. L. Sad A.},
  title = {A novel adhesion receptor in Dictyostelium.},
  journal = {J. Cell Biol.},
  year = {2002},
  volume = {159},
  pages = {1109–1119},
  owner = {Giovanni},
  timestamp = {2013.06.21}
}
```

The Tex file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\begin{document}

Here is an example \cite{Deryugina1998} \\
What about this one \cite{Fey2002}

\bibliography{paht_to_bib-file/bibfile}

\end{document}
```

Instead of a comma, I get an space on the authors' names in the Bibliography.

What should I change?

Thank you in advanced for your replies!

Comment: Don't use commas in your `.bib` file to separate authors, but write "and": "Fey P. and Stephens S. and ...".

Comment: At the end, you've chosen to put your bibliography in a subfolder of your `.tex` file...

Comment: @karlkoeller the thing is that I'm using 3 different softwares to write my Project: Docear (that includes JabRef) and TexMaker.
Once I finish the Project, I'll do as I asked before... I didn't notice about it while sending the question. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for having accepted the answer that solves your problem. This is the right way to go! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma in author names for BibTeX are reserved to write names as *Lastname, Firstname*. Different authors are separated with "and".

While you can write *Firstname Lastname* (no comma), it is sometimes necessary to use the other form: when the last name contains several tokens as in *Per Brinch Hansen*. BibTex would think that *Brinch* is a first name, therefore you have to write it as *Brinch Hansen, Per*. The comma is also needed to separate a *Jr* part. Because of all this it would be too hard to parse a string of several authors with comma also being a separator for different names, hence the usage of "and".

Comment: +1 for having turned a comment that solves a problem in an answer ;-)